# what does Scheme `define` expression return?

Tags: function, scheme, lisp, higher-order-functions, function-definition

I'm super new to this language and I came across a problem. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

Basically, I want to define a higher-order function `make-adder`. Here is my code.

```
(define (make-adder num)
  (define (foo x)
    (+ x num)))

(define adder (make-adder 5))

(adder 8) ;error points to here
```

But, I wonder why I got this error message.

```
# Error: expected
#     4
# but got
#     Traceback (most recent call last):
#       ...
#     SchemeError: str is not callable: foo
```

another interpreter I use also gave me an error but in a different way

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
0   (adder 8) [frame = Global]
Unable to pass parameters into the Symbol 'foo'
```

First, I wanted to know why I cannot use this code to define the `make-adder` higher order function like I always did in Python.

Second, I suppose that what a `define` procedure expression returns is a string ? (because it said `str foo is not callable`) But when I tried to test it out

```
scm> (define (foo x) (+ 1 x))
foo
scm> (string? (define (foo x) (+ 1 x)))
#f
```

So it turns out that it's not a string. I am so confused. What does `foo` stand for here? Is it a string or something else? Why I cannot call from it?

Hope anyone can help me out. Thank you.

Comment: good question, well asked.  cheers, :)

Comment: The RNRS reports until R5RS underspecified all forms that was mererly for side effects. Some implementations, like MIT Scheme, did return values that programmers might find useful, but it isn't portable to make use of these values. Some implementation might also allow `define` in other places than the report specifies so while using `define` as an expression might work in your implementation it is guaranteed to fail under R5RS in Racket. In other implementation it might silently fail since R5RS doesn't dictate how a non Scheme program should be handled.

Answer (score 4):

Something that's not clear from the other answers is that *`(define ...)` is not an expression*: it's a *definition*: a special bit of syntax which can occur in only certain special places allowed by the language.  As such it simply doesn't have a value, because it can't occur anywhere where an expression is allowed.

From [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-4.html#node_sec_1.2):

> Definitions are not expressions, and cannot appear in all places where an expression can occur. Moreover, a definition has no value.

[R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/) is not quite so clear on this, but says (this is chapter 5):

> A Scheme program consists of a sequence of expressions, definitions, and syntax definitions. [...]
>
> [...]
> Definitions are valid in some, but not all, contexts where expressions are allowed. They are valid only at the top level of a <program> and at the beginning of a <body>.

R7Rs says something similar.

What this means in particular is that definitions can't freely be used where expressions are expected:  You can't say

```
(let ((x (define y 2)))
  ...)
```

for instance: that's simply not legal Scheme.

In particular you can't ever have a definition where its value (or lack of one) can mean anything.  And one consequence of this is that I think your program is probably not legal Scheme.

It's not legal because the syntax for `lambda` is something like:

`(lambda <formals> <body>)`

Where `<body>` is

> 'a sequence of *zero or more* definitions followed by *one or more* expressions.'

(Text from [R7RS](https://small.r7rs.org/), my emphasis.)

What this means is that the body of a `lambda` expression should have at least one expression:

- `(lambda ())` is not legal as it has no expressions;
- `(lambda () (define x 1))` is *also* illegal as it has one definition but still no expressions;
- `(lambda () (define x 1) x)` is legal as it has one definition and one expression;
- `(lambda () 1)` is also legal (no definitions, one expression).

Of course implementations may allow (and clearly sometimes do allow) expressions equivalent to `(lambda ())`, but those expressions are not conforming Scheme.

This property of `define` in Scheme is very confusing to people who come from a traditional Lisp background (like me), where the nearest equivalent forms *are* expressions (there are still weird-non-expression things which can only go in some places, such as declarations, but function and variable definitions are not one of them).

Comment: "simply doesn't have a value" you mean it *should* be so, in a conformant implementation. apparently OP tried it in two (online?) interpreters, and both returned *something*.  arguably it could have even been the function that was just defined. or green cheese. :)

Comment: @WillNess:  Yes, of course.  I always prefer the green cheese myself!

Answer (score 1):

It's a symbol.

```
#;1> (symbol? 'foo)
#t
```

How about:

```
(define (make-adder num)
  (define (foo x)
    (+ x num))
  foo)
```

Comment: hi, so I can have 2 return expressions for make-adder? the first is define (foo x) and the second is foo? amazingly it does work but I wonder why?

Comment: @bznn  A function returns the value of the last form. One can have multiple forms in a function body.

Answer (score 1):

You should return anonymous function ([lambda](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lambda.html?q=lambda#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._lambda%29%29)):

```
(define (make-adder num)
  (lambda (x) (+ num x)))

(define adder (make-adder 5))
(adder 8)
```

Value returned by `(define (foo x) (+ 1 x))` depends on development environment (for example, DrRacket returns nothing), because [define](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html?q=define#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._define%29%29) has no return value. Your IDE probably returns [symbol](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/symbols.html?q=symbol#%28tech._symbol%29) (try predicate [symbol?](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._symbol%7E3f%29%29)) or just function name.

Answer (score 1):

It defines the `foo`, but doesn't return the `foo`. It looks like it returns its *name*, either as a string in one implementation, or a *symbol*, in another. This is probably implementation-dependent, or "undefined", in the language definition, the Report.

Scheme prides itself on being an *expression-oriented language*, meaning, every expression returns its value. It so happens that the value of the `define` expression is not the value of the entity (here, function `foo`) it is defining, which might be a bit counter-intuitive.

So either return `foo` after defining it, as shown in the first answer, or just use the anonymous function (`lambda`) as the last expression as shown in the second answer, since the `lambda` form's value *is* the function itself (as opposed to its name, or being undefined at all).

In Scheme, *functions* are callable, but symbols or strings are, of course, not.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think I am getting started to understand it. So let us say it returns a symbol, I wonder why, after evaluating this define expression, the symbol (foo) is not bind to the newly evaluated expression(the function foo), but only return and tell me it's a symbol? If it does bind to that function, I suppose I should be able to use this symbol to refer to that function instantly after the expression is returned.

Comment: the symbol might be bound to a function, but you can't call a symbol. in `(let ((a ...exp1...) (b ...exp2...)) (a b))`, the *value* of expression `...exp1...` is used, and is called as a function, with the value of expression `...exp2...`. so *that* value, bound to  `a`, must be a function. if evaluating the first expression returned a symbol, we'd get an error, "symbol is not callable".

Comment: again, in the piece of code `(a b)`, `a` is a symbol; but the language uses that symbol's value on its own. we don't have to turn a symbol into its value, that's what the language is doing. (we can manipulate code with macros, but that's an advanced topic).